# Dynamically .Skip() and .Take() IQueryable<AnonymousType>

Tags: c#, casting, anonymous-types

I have a grid control that have a `DataSource` property as `Object`, Now I want to cast my `DataSource` to `IQueryable<T>` to take and skip Like this code

`var pagedData = ((IQueryable<T>) DataSource).Skip(20).Take(10);`

But I don't know how can I cast `Object` to `IQueryable<T>`? also most of the time type of data is `IQueryable<AnonymousType>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will almost certainly be better ways to deal with this, but to answer your question as asked, you can use `dynamic`:

```
private static IQueryable<T> GetInteriorElements<T>
                (IQueryable<T> source, int skip, int take)
{
    return source.Skip(skip).Take(take);
}
```

And call it as:

```
object DataSource = ...

// The real question is: what are you now going to do with this?
var pagedData = GetInteriorElements((dynamic)DataSource, 10, 20);
```

If you are on .NET 3.5, you'll have to use reflection, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to properly define a class. Anonymous types are great when they are wholly self-contained within the method that created them. When you demonstate the need to use them elsewhere in code, document the type via a class definition and then you can use the class anywhere you need it, including in a cast. Once you have created a class definition, simply reference the class by name wherever you need it.

Query:

```
...
select new ClassName // name the class
{
    ...
}
```

Method return type

```
public IQueryable<ClassName> GetData()
```

And cast

```
var data = (IQueryable<ClassName>)theDataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [`PagedDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx) as the source for your Grid and let that do the work for you?

[Paging using PagedDataSource class - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/pagingBySreejith%20Thathanattu.aspx)